# Google maps js with jsf

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using jsf with google maps, when I put the jsf tags (h:....) and within one of them is the <div id:map> or I use <h:head>, the map does not load correctly. The following error message appears: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild').

I need to use the tags (h:head, h:body...) in my project. Any solution?

Thank you so much.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   
    <h:head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Prueba 01</title>
        <script src="../js/googleMaps.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
    </h:head>
   
    <h:body>
        <h1>Saludando</h1>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel>esto es una prueba</h:outputLabel>
      
            <div id="map"> </div>
      
        </h:form>
      
      
        <script
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jsv=3&amp;MY_API_KEYkey=A&amp;callback=initializeGMaps">
        </script>

    </h:body>

</html>
    

    googleMaps.js
    
    var geocoder,
    directionService,
    directionDisplay,
    map;
    
    function initializeGMaps(){
       var rendererOptions = {draggable: true};
       geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()  
       directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
            
       var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09023980307208,-4.833984375);
          
       var myOptions = {
           zoom: 4,
           center: latlng,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       }
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
       directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    };
    
    
    style.css
    #map {
      width:650px;
      height:350px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your Google Maps Javascript API v3 script include (missing "?" and "async"):

```
<script 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jsv=3&amp;MY_API_KEYkey=A&amp;callback=initializeGMaps">
</script>
```

should be:

```
<script 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&amp;callback=initializeGMaps" async>
</script>
```

(you can include the `v=3` if you want, but it isn't required)
[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
//    googleMaps.js

var geocoder,
  directionService,
  directionDisplay,
  map;

function initializeGMaps() {
  var rendererOptions = {
    draggable: true
  };
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09023980307208, -4.833984375);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
};
```

```css
/* 

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
*/


/* style.css */

#map {
  width: 650px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Prueba 01</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
  <h1>Saludando</h1>
  <h:form>
    <h:outputLabel>esto es una prueba</h:outputLabel>

    <div id="map"> </div>

  </h:form>


  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&amp;callback=initializeGMaps" async>
  </script>

</h:body>

</html>
```